# Why is only the second .click() working?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have two chunks of code here, but only the first is functioning correctly. I'm not sure why. Does it have to do with the "download" attribute? Why? Or, is it because dl isn't correctly referncing the right object? Very confused here, been going at it for an hour or two now.

(Also, is there a way to click an object without appending it to the DOM? Guessing not.)

```
// WORKING
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([this.list.join("\r\n")], {type: "octet/stream"}));
a.download = fileName;
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);

// NOT WORKING
var dl = $('<a>',{
  style: 'display: none',
  download: fileName,
  href: window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([this.list.join("\r\n")], {type: "octet/stream"}))
});
$('body').append(dl);
dl.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(dl.href);
```

Comment: where is it failing?

Comment: Nothing is downloaded. dl is appended correctly, attributes and all, but .click() simply doesn't seem to work - or if it is, it's not doing anything.

First example works fine, and I download a file with the blob data titled whatever fileName is at the time.

Comment: `dl[0].click();` will work, you want to call native anchor click method, not triggering any jQuery click event

Comment: As A. Wolff said, `dl[0].click()` works just fine, without the need to add it to the DOM

Comment: Excuse me for being incredibly naive, but why did that work? The importance of the `[0]` syntax is lost on me.

Comment: Use the native element (that you can find inside the jQuery element): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782534/why-jquery-cannot-trigger-native-click-on-an-anchor-tag

Comment: BTW, `dl.href` should be `dl[0].href` or `dl.get(0).href` or `dl.prop('href')` still for the same reason

Comment: Anchor elements don't navigate via `jquery.click()` call. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/773639/1305911

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is a DOM object which has a `click` method, the second is a jQuery object which behaves as an array - to obtain the first DOM element from the array you do so like reading any normal javascript array using `dl[0]`. You can then call the `click` method on this object, which does not need to be added to the DOM.

```
dl[0].click()
```