# Jquery selection involving selection inside anonymous elements

Tags: jquery

I'm having some difficulty selecting the a element inside the second li via jquery.

```html
<ul id="pf-filters" class="pf-option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
 <li>
  <a class="selected" href="#filter" data-option-value="*">Everything</a>
 </li>            
 <li>
  <a href="#filter" data-option-value=".current">Current</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#filter" data-option-value=".world">World</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Via jquery I'm trying to select it by doing:

```
$("#pf-filters li:nth-child(2) a").click();
```

but i'm not getting (the filter in this case) to change.
If you need more details about the problem please ask.

Comment: your id is `#pf-filters`, not `#pf-items`. Is it a typo?

Comment: `.click()` will only invoke the click events bound with it. If you want to invoke the natural click then you have to do,`$("#pf-items li:nth-child(2) a")[0].click();`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy thanks, that solves it, but I'm curious, why the [0] in front of the selector? Its the first time seeing that kind of syntax.

Comment: @ddrjm This may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782534/why-jquery-cannot-trigger-native-click-on-an-anchor-tag and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy from what I gather, its use is to select the actual DOM element instead of a event handler? is this correct?

Comment: @ddrjm Yes it is used for grabbing the javascript object present underneath the jquery object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#pf-items li:nth-child(2) a")[0].click();`

Its the answer. Check the comments to my question to understand why.