# Unexpected results when clicking link with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if this is just a simple oversight on my end, but what am I doing wrong? I would like the results of `regular.js`, but why isn't this working in jquery?

```
html:
<a href="" class="foobar" id="foobar">click me</a>

regular.js:
document.getElementById('foobar').click();
// this results in the page continuously clicking and reloading the page


jquery.js:
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#foobar").trigger('click');
    },5);
});
// this waits for page to load before executing, but does nothing.
```

Comment: When you use jQuery's `.trigger('click')` it calls any click handler that you've bound, but does *not* trigger the DOM element's default click navigation behaviour. You can do `$("#foobar")[0].click()` instead if you want it to work like your regular.js. You don't need the timeout. Is that what you're asking? (I don't know why you'd want a continuous click/reload...)

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh okay, gotcha! No I do not actually have a use for continuously clicking it, but only need to it click once in an automation script using `phantomjs`. I just wasn't sure why I was not seeing the same results. So that's how I ended up on StackOverflow :)

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782534/why-jquery-cannot-trigger-native-click-on-an-anchor-tag).

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> **Trigger**: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

You should replace `.trigger('click')` with `.click()`

---

### Update

After reading the comments and searching some more, I found the following:

#### The problem

jQuery can activate methods bound using:

- jQuery (`.bind`, `.on`, `.click` etc)
- native binding `element.onclick = function() {}`.

But if a method was added using `element.addEventListener()`, jQuery's `.click()` and `.trigger()` will fail silently.

#### The solution

Using `element.click()` activates all bound methods. So does a real click from mouse, but that is trivial.

Also, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) states, and the OP has pointed out, the following:

> The click() method will not cause an  element to initiate navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received.

I have tried in Chrome 52 and Firefox 48, on Ubuntu 14, and it seems to work for me. Still, unsure if what MDN states is false.

Comment: *"You should replace .trigger('click') with .click()"* - Why? It wouldn't change the behaviour. (By the way, the jQuery docs aren't quite accurate with regard to "all...behaviours", because for an anchor in fact the jQuery `.trigger()` doesn't cause the default anchor navigation behaviour.)

Comment: native script will do ,`$('')[0].click()`

Comment: @passion I need to simulate a click on an `<a>` tag in an automation script (phantoms), but cannot use the `click()` method because according to the first paragraph in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click , an `<a>` is the only element not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why yours is not working - working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tr04uy3/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click',"#foobar",function(){alert("hello world")})

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#foobar").trigger('click');
    },5);
});
```